Definitively disable the automatic IPv6 address configuration
I have this Unbound container with a static IPv6 address.
It is based on the Alpine Linux distribution (alpinelinux/unbound:latest), so it has limited configurations.
Whenever a client makes a query to Unbound's static IPv6 address, it responds back with the source auto configured SLAAC address.
This causes some queries to fail.

So, I tried to disable the IPv6 autoconfiguration. With sysctl, by disabling net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf, it shouldn't configure the SLAAC address, right?
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0

# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0

Then, I restarted the container, but the interface still gets the local prefix and sets the SLAAC address.
I then tried to add these settings into the /etc/sysctl.conf file, but it didn't work.
# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# content of this file will override /etc/sysctl.d/*
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0

# sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0

Any tips on how to definitively disable the automatic IPv6 address configuration?

The router RAs tell the host how to configure or not.

Try turning off accept_ra too

Hey Rob. I did try to turn off RA acceptance too, but it didn't work.

You usually set such settings in the config file of your network manager (ifconfig, NetworkManager, systemd, wicked, netplan). Read its documentation.
